# passing a variable (id) from html to external js file with functions

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm novel with javascript, and I trying to develop a webpage with dynamics graphs using for that canvas, html 5 and javascript. I wouldn't like to mix html "code" with javascript code, so I decided to keep it separated and call from html the javascript functions. The fact is that when I try to pass my **canvas Id** to javascript function I'm making a mistake and I have no idea how to fix it. This is my html code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="Funciones.js">
        window.onload = drawRectangulo('myCanvas');
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Canvas Example:</h1>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

And my JavaScript file is like this:

```
function drawRectangulo(idCanvas)
{
    var Canvas = document.getElementById('idCanvas');
    var context = Canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.fillRect(50,0,10,150);
}
```

I don't know if the call to drawRectangulo function on javascript file is right, and if I'm passing the canvas's id right: **window.onload = drawRectangulo('myCanvas');** ¿How should I pass the Id from the html file to the js function?. Should I use: ('', "",) or should I create a new variable, initiate it with the canvas's id and pass it to the function? Am I processing good the variable id inside JavaScript function?

Answer (score 2):

You need to do this:

```
window.onload = function () {
    drawRectangulo('myCanvas');
}
```

Your code is *calling* drawRectangulo as soon as it runs, and assigning the result of the call (which is `undefined`) to `window.onload`.

**Edit** based on Dan's comment: you also need to change this:

```
document.getElementById('idCanvas');
```

to this:

```
document.getElementById(idCanvas);
```

**Edit 2**: You also need to separate your imported script from your inline script, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="Funciones.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = drawRectangulo('myCanvas');
</script>
```

A single `<script>` element can either import a script from another file, or define an inline script, or both.  (That explains why moving your inline script elsewhere in your HTML made it work.)

Comment: The `drawRectangulo(idCanvas)` function does not appear to be using the parameter `idCanvas`

Comment: Thanks guys. I've changed as you said and It's still doesn't work. It doesn't run by itself on window.load. I've tried in js console to run: **drawRectangulo("myCanvas");** and it painted it. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I think this

```
var Canvas = document.getElementById('idCanvas');
```

should be

```
var Canvas = document.getElementById(idCanvas);
```

With those apostrophes there, you're not referencing the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know why it doesn't work. I have made this change on html and now is working right:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="Funciones.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

        window.onload = function (){
            drawRectangulo('myCanvas');
        }
    </script>

    <h1>Canvas Example:</h1>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

I took out the **window.onload** from the header to the body and it worked. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: See my updated answer.  It's not about moving your script to the body, but about splitting apart the two pieces of script that you have.